# composer install magento2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2, composer

I try to install magento2.3.5-p1 by use composer, when it is finished the folder structure looks like: [image] Anyone knows why it is like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this command composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition and it is working properly . From the screenshot I can come to conclusion is that your download was not completed or might have interrupted.